# How to change value of global variable inside function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I know this has been asked before, but my case seems to be little bit different

I have two js files, one for logic, one for objects which includes data about movie(s)

my first file looks like this

```
var movieTitle = document.getElementById("movieTitle");
var rating = document.getElementById("rating");
var movieYear = document.getElementById("movieYear");
var movieDuration = document.getElementById("movieDuration");
var actorName = document.getElementById("actorName");
var actorRole = document.getElementById("actorRole");
var actorNameI = document.getElementById("actorName2");
var actorRoleII = document.getElementById("actorRole2");
var testClick = document.getElementById("testClick");

var movie = movieI;

movieTitle.innerHTML = "Title: " + movie.title;
movieYear.innerHTML = "release Year: " + movie.releaseYear;
movieDuration.innerHTML = "Duration: " + movie.duration;

actorName.innerHTML = "Name: " + movie.actors[0].name;
actorRole.innerHTML = "Role: " + movie.actors[0].role;

actorNameI.innerHTML = "Name: " + movie.actors[1].name;
actorRoleII.innerHTML = "Role: " + movie.actors[1].role;

rating.innerHTML = "Rating: " + movie.rating;

testClick.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var movie = movieII
})
```

file from where i fetch objects looks like this

```
var movieI = {
    title: "Titanic",
    releaseYear: 1997,
    rating: "PG21",
    duration: "3 hours",

    actors: [

    {
        name: "leonardo dicaprio",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    {
        name: "kate winslet",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    ]
};


var movieII = {
    title: "Wolf of wall street",
    releaseYear: 2013,
    rating: "PG18",
    duration: "2H 30M",

    actors: [

    {
        name: "leonardo dicaprio",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    {
        name: "jonah hill",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    ]
};
```

on my first js file i have following function

```
testClick.addEventListener("click", function(){
    movie = movieII
})
```

this is supposed to modify value of movie variable and set it to movieII so it can switch/access  second object(movieII) from my objects file, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: The function in the first file says `var movie =`, not `movie =`. That makes it a local variable, not the global variable. Get rid of `var`, like you wrote at the end of the question.

Comment: Note that assigning to `movie` will not change any of the `innerHTML` values that were set in the first script.

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: all of that xxx.innerHTML code needs to be in a function. That code runs once and is done. It does not magically keep running and updating. Update the variable, call the function to update the UI.

Comment: heres codepen. thanks https://codepen.io/solutresr/pen/ExLgyMb

Comment: https://codepen.io/solutresr/pen/ExLgyMb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to use function and parameters for this project?

Here was the docs
[Function in js](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that updating the object doesn't change what has already been shown in the HTML, you need to update your HTML with the new information but only after it changed in the variable.

You can do that linear ( as you have in your code) or just creating a function that you can call every time and will help you avoiding duplicated code.

Here is one way you can do that:

```
//Titanic

let movieI = {
    title: "Titanic",
    releaseYear: 1997,
    rating: "PG21",
    duration: "3 hours",

    actors: [

    {
        name: "leonardo dicaprio",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    {
        name: "kate winslet",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    ]
};


let movieII = {
    title: "Wolf of wall street",
    releaseYear: 2013,
    rating: "PG18",
    duration: "2H 30M",

    actors: [

    {
        name: "leonardo dicaprio",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    {
        name: "jonah hill",
        role: "role goes here"
    },

    ]
};

let actorsBox = document.getElementById("actos-box");
let movieTitle = document.getElementById("movieTitle");
let rating = document.getElementById("rating");
let movieYear = document.getElementById("movieYear");
let movieDuration = document.getElementById("movieDuration");
let actorName = document.getElementById("actorName");
let actorRole = document.getElementById("actorRole");
let actorNameI = document.getElementById("actorName2");
let actorRoleII = document.getElementById("actorRole2");
let testClick = document.getElementById("testClick");

let movie = movieI;

updateMovie();


testClick.addEventListener("click", function(){
    movie = movieII
  updateMovie();
})

function updateMovie(){
  movieTitle.innerHTML = "Title: " + movie.title;
  movieYear.innerHTML = "release Year: " + movie.releaseYear;
  movieDuration.innerHTML = "Duration: " + movie.duration;

  actorName.innerHTML = "Name: " + movie.actors[0].name;
  actorRole.innerHTML = "Role: " + movie.actors[0].role;

  actorNameI.innerHTML = "Name: " + movie.actors[1].name;
  actorRoleII.innerHTML = "Role: " + movie.actors[1].role;

  rating.innerHTML = "Rating: " + movie.rating;
}
```

Also I highly recommend you not to use var as it can do weird things you might not want to do.

Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp) for learning more about let variables.